# How do I solve Error importing a css file with next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, next.js

Error:

```
./node_modules/quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.css
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

In `_app.js`, I have:

```
import "quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.css";
```

And in `next.config.js`:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");


if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
    require.extensions['.less'] = () => {};
    require.extensions['.css'] = file => {};
}

module.exports = withPlugins([
    withImages,
    withCSS
], {
    devIndicators: {
        autoPrerender: false,
    },
    webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
...
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [emoji css](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/contentco/quill-emoji/master/dist/quill-emoji.css) seems to include content of `data:image` and loads svg's inline.

I was trying with multiple loaders and couldn't find the right sequence, you probably need `resolve-url-loader` in some specific sequence.

It maybe best to just link it using `next/head` and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

I think the emoji icons are svg. You might need an svg loader to solve this problem.

next-images adds support for jpg, jpeg, svg, png, ico, webp and gif images.

NOTE: I have not tested this with quill

This is an example snippet.

```
const withImages = require("next-images");

module.exports = withImages({
    webpack(config, options) {
        return config;
    }
});
```

Comment: Same error. I'm using `next-compose-plugins` with `@zeit/next-css` and `next-images`